# Does bringing an activity to the foreground call its onCreate method?

Tags: android

Pretty self explanatory question. If I start activity B from activity A and the user subsequently presses back or home, activity B is destroyed and activity A comes back into the foreground. Now is activity A's `onCreate` method guaranteed to be called? It seems that way to me. Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When Activity A comes into foreground it is always guaranteed that Activity A's `onStart()` is called. You can put `log.i()` inside `onCreate(), onStart()` callbacks to check yourself. But, if you are in low-memory, and GC, by chance, clear the `savedInstanceState` state of Activity A, then the system needs to call `onCreate()` again.

So based on the internal condition of the system, sometimes it calls `onCreate()`, sometimes `onStart()`, or sometimes `onResume()`. Nothing is guaranteed.

[image]

You see above picture, the back arrow pointed to onCreate(), sometimes onStart(), sometimes onPause().

Comment: Low memory might cause your activity to be destroyed (and subsequently recreated when you return to it), but that does not "clear" `savedInstanceState`. In fact, `savedInstanceState` will have whatever was written to it, and that's exactly what allows the system to safely destroy and recreate activities.

Comment: @BenP. There are different version of savedInstanceState based on LifeCycycle. savedInstanceState is instance of Bundle. Bundle, by default, is not persistent. On low memroy, if savedInstanceState of onStart() is destroyed, then OS uses savedInstanceState of onCreate() to  recreate the Activity again. You have to use PersistentBundle to guarantee that you can resume any state of Activity.

Comment: So `onStart` is not guaranteed to be called? What about `onResume`?

Comment: @the_prole, nothing is guaranteed in Activity. It is based on different condition. All the callbacks like onCreate(), onStaret() etc are triggered by  the system.

Comment: @the_prole, you yourself see above picture -- lifecycle flowchart posted by Matias, sometimes, the back arrow pointed to onCreate(), sometimes onStart(), sometimes onPause().

Comment: @UddhavGautam but `onResume` is the very last call back called according to the life cycle diagram. It must be called.

Comment: @the_prole, if Activity A was already destroyed, then onCreate() and onStart() get called but not onResume()

Comment: Uddhav's comments above are mostly wrong. If the activity is starting up for the first time or being recreated after destruction, onCreate(), onStart(), and onResume() will all be called.

Comment: @Ben  My answer includes that as well.

Comment: @UddhavGautam What if launchMode of Activity A is specified as "singleTop" ? Then also onCreate() will be called .

Comment: @UddhavGautam I don't know how someone can be so sure about things that they do not understand clearly .

Comment: @RishabhMaurya, singleTop is making duplicate of savedInstanceStae. In this scenario, OS copies savedInstance to somewhere in persistent storage. And when you press home or back button it restores from that saved saedInstanceState. So, in this case system will resume Activity A. My answer is not about providing fix and rigit answer; it's about understanding.

Answer (score 2):

No, only `onResume()` is guaranteed to be called.

[image]

Comment: if Activity A was already destroyed, then onCreate() and onStart() get called but not onResume()

Comment: I just said that only onResume is guaranteed to be called.. if the activity is destroyed by the OS then yes, onCreate is called again...

Answer (score 0):

No, your parent activity can be destroyed at any time, as it may call onResume().

It depends on the phone memory, try to do it on a low specs phone and probably it will call onCreate()